# How to generate random cartesian coordinates given distance constraint in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to generate *N* random coordinates for a 2D plane. The distance between any two points are given (number of distance is *N(N - 1) / 2).* For example, say I need to generate 3 points i.e. A, B, C. I have the distance between pair of them i.e. `distAB`, `distAC` and `distBC`.
Is there any built-in function in MATLAB that can do this? Basically, I'm looking for something that is the reverse of `pdist()` function.

My initial idea was to choose a point (say A is the origin). Then, I can randomly find B and C being on two different circles with radii `distAB` and `distAC`. But then the distance between B and C might not satisfy `distBC` and I'm not sure how to proceed if this happens. And I think this approach will get very complicated if *N* is a large number.

Comment: So, you basically want to plot a known triangle at a random location and rotation?  Randomly pick the origin and a rotation. Then use trig to determine the actual point locations.

Comment: @MattB. Actually not just an ordinary triangle, but a [Reuleaux triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a technique called classical multidimensional scaling. It will work fine and losslessly if the distances you have correspond to distances between valid points in 2-D. Luckily there is a function in MATLAB that does exactly this: [`cmdscale`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/cmdscale.html). Once you run this function on your distance matrix, you can treat the first two columns in the first output argument as the points you need.

Answer (score 5):

Elaborating on Ansaris answer I produced the following. It assumes a valid distance matrix provided, calculates positions in 2D based on cmdscale, does a random rotation (random translation could be added also), and visualizes the results:

```
%Distance matrix
D = [0 2 3; ...
     2 0 4; ...
     3 4 0];

%Generate point coordinates based on distance matrix
Y = cmdscale(D);

[nPoints dim] = size(Y);

%Add random rotation
randTheta = 2*pi*rand(1);
Rot = [cos(randTheta) -sin(randTheta); sin(randTheta) cos(randTheta) ];
Y = Y*Rot;

%Visualization
figure(1);clf;
plot(Y(:,1),Y(:,2),'.','markersize',20)
hold on;t=0:.01:2*pi;
for r = 1 : nPoints - 1 
    for c = r+1 : nPoints
        plot(Y(r,1)+D(r,c)*sin(t),Y(r,2)+D(r,c)*cos(t));
        plot(Y(c,1)+D(r,c)*sin(t),Y(c,2)+D(r,c)*cos(t));
    end
end
```

[image]